# Django Model Form field data not displaying

Tags: django, django-forms, modelform

So I am trying to figure out why my dropdown menu will not display the list of collections for the user to pick from.

Form Screenshot: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIrq6.png

---

```
Here is the Form.py file class used for this problem:
```

class ProductForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
model = listing
fields = '**all**'

---

_---------------------------------------------
Here is the user form VIEW:

```
def index(request):

form = ProductForm
if request.method == 'POST':

    form = ProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        
context = {'form':form}
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

---

---

**Here is also the code for the 2 models here:**

```
class Collection(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)




def __str__(self) -> str:
    return self.title

class Meta:
    ordering = ['title']


class listing(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
description = models.TextField()
unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
inventory = models.IntegerField()
last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)

vendors = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=False)
```

---

I'm somewhat new to django and just trying to understand why for the form it won't display the list of collections in the dropdown.

Comment: Post your `form.py`, if you are using one, and the `view.py` you are using. (not the full file just each function)

Comment: Your `forms.py` code is not properly formatted here.

Comment: @Collins Life do you have data in Collection in database?

Comment: @inquirer You are absolutely amazing now I didn't have any but now it works I created a product and added it to the collection and now from the form on the webpage I can now see the collection available. Honestly thank you so much.

Comment: @CollinsLife upvote if I create an answer?

Comment: @inquirer Not sure what upvote is I'm really new to stack overflow and by the way I have another question to ask you. I will create another post just trying to solve this problem.